# Best way for Iteration & extract data on an IndexedSeq in scala

Tags: scala

What is the best way to iterate and extract the data in scala with an indexedseq were there are indexed specific data

```
val data
=IndexedSeq(0x00,0x0F,0x33,0x35,0x35,0x35,0x36,0x35,0x30,0x37,0x31,0x33,0x30,0x38,0x31,0x30,0x33,0x43,0x4D,0x54,0x4D,0x31,0x2E,0x30,0x30,0x32)
```

> Device Sends Connection command having length 14 bytes.
>
> 00 0F 33 35 35
>   35 36 35 30 37 31 33 30 38 31 30 33 43 4D 54 4D 31 2E 30 30 32
>
> Header-2 Bytes Device ID 16 Bytes Firmware version 8 Bytes

I tried below for a manual check on each index

```
if(data(0)==0x00 && data(1)==0x0F){
  //New Connection

  val deviceId=(data.slice(2,17).map(_.toChar)).mkString
  val firmwareVersion=(data.slice(18,25).map(_.toChar)).mkString

  println(deviceId)
  println(firmwareVersion)
}
```

Comment: Best way to do what? According which criteria?what have you already tried?which issue?

Comment: @cchantep right now i do this
if(data(0)==0x00 && data(1)==0x0F){
  //New Connection

  val deviceId=(data.slice(2,17).map(_.toChar)).mkString
  val firmwareVersion=(data.slice(18,25).map(_.toChar)).mkString

  println(deviceId)
  println(firmwareVersion)
}

Comment: What you are doing currently seems to work fine. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Just want to know how can i improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pattern matching:

```
val data = Seq(0x00,0x0F,0x33,0x35,0x35,0x35,0x36,0x35,0x30,0x37,0x31,0x33,0x30,0x38,0x31,0x30,0x33,0x43,0x4D,0x54,0x4D,0x31,0x2E,0x30,0x30,0x32)

data match {
  case 0x00::0x0F::xs => 
    val deviceId=(xs.take(15).map(_.toChar)).mkString
    val firmwareVersion=(data.slice(18,25).map(_.toChar)).mkString
    println(deviceId)
    println(firmwareVersion)
  case other => // handle unexpected data
}
```